# QuickOSM no residential value with building key

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I want to use QuickOSM to extract residential buildings with type (terrace, apartment, detached, semidetached). On the website i see the key and values but in my QGIS/QuickOSM the value is not available. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features#Tags_for_individual_houses

Does someone know why or how?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the dropdown only shows some (the most common?) values for a tag. You can type anything you like in:

[image]

By the way, I'm not sure "building=terrace" is used properly in many places - the wiki says it should be used to tag an entire row of houses in a terrace, not individual houses, yet:

[image]

Comment: in your image the building type is displayed. When I inspect a building the value is 'yes'. I want to load in all buildings with types. when I used 'terrace' as value, there were no results.

Comment: So is your question "Why isn't this building tagged as "terrace" when its a terrace?" Because as is the Q reads like "I can't search on building=terrace" in quickOSM. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If I see it correctly your building is tagged as a terrace building, right? How did you achieve that?

Comment: Somebody in the past tagged it that way. OSM data is not authoritative, or guaranteed to be complete or correct. Its like wikipedia, anyone can edit it.

Comment: now i get it. thx